# AWS CLI to find out list of active reserved instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am trying to find out list of reserved instances that are active.

```
aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances --filters  "Name=instance-state-State,Values=active" --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[]'
```

The above command does not work, and I think the `Name` field is not right.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: I figure out a part of my problem:
`aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances --filters Name=state,Values=active`

But how can I only get Instance type with instance count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another take on it. Put the search for

```
State == `active`
```

into the query statement. The output includes labels as well. By the way, changing from single-quotes around the query to double-quotes (on a mac) will require you to escape the backticks with backslashes.

```
aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances --query 'ReservedInstances[?State == `active`].{Count: InstanceCount, Type: InstanceType}' --output json
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "Count": 50,
        "Type": "t2.medium"
    },
    {
        "Count": 3,
        "Type": "m4.2xlarge"
    },
    {
        "Count": 17,
        "Type": "m3.large"
    },
    {
        "Count": 3,
        "Type": "m3.2xlarge"
    },
    {
        "Count": 2,
        "Type": "m3.2xlarge"
    },
    {
        "Count": 3,
        "Type": "m3.xlarge"
    },
    {
        "Count": 6,
        "Type": "m4.4xlarge"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
aws ec2 describe-reserved-instances --filter Name=state,Values=active
        --query 'ReservedInstances[*][InstanceType,InstanceCount]'
```

Output:

```
[
    [
        "m3.medium",
        4
    ],
    [
        "c4.large",
        5
    ]
]
```